# WMI Issues when installing SQL 2014 (The specified module could not be found)

Tags: windows-10, services, wmi

I am trying to install SQL 2014 on my Window 10 laptop and during rule checking I receive the following error:

[image: SQL error]

When I check for the Windows Management Instrumentation service on my laptop I find only Winmgmt which cannot be started due to the following error:

[image: Services]

I see a lot of sites I have visited mentions the `%windir%\system32\Wbem` folder which does not exist on the machine. And running `winmgmt` commands on the system to rebuild the repositories states that it is not recognized as internal or external command.

I have another PC with the exact same version of Windows 10 and no issues.

I have tried running `sfc /scannow` but get the below error:

[image: cmd error]

Here are the errors in CBS.log:

`2016-01-12 16:29:28, Error                 CSI    00003a8c (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #6719792# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectFileSystemProvider::SysCreateFile(flags = (AllowSharingViolation), handle = {provider=NULL, handle=0, name= ("null")}, da = (SYNCHRONIZE|FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES), oa = @0x10f864af70->OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {s:48; rd:NULL; on:[107]"\??\C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_wstorflt.inf.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_en-us_a5cd47a48d2fba30"; a:(OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE)}, iosb = @0x10f864af50, as = (null), fa = 0, sa = (FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE), cd = FILE_OPEN, co = (FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT|0x00004000), eab = NULL, eal = 0, disp = Invalid)
[gle=0xd0000034]

2016-01-12 16:29:28, Error                 CSI    00003a8d@2016/1/12:14:29:28.534 (F) base\wcp\sil\merged\ntu\ntsystem.cpp(3004): Error STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND originated in function Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectFileSystemProvider::SysCreateFile expression: (null)
[gle=0x80004005]

2016-01-12 16:29:28, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log to WER report.

2016-01-12 16:29:28, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160111133116.log to WER report.

2016-01-12 16:29:28, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160111112335.log to WER report.

2016-01-12 16:29:28, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160110181321.log to WER report.

2016-01-12 16:29:28, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160104101551.cab to WER report.

2016-01-12 16:29:28, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20151112020242.cab to WER report.

2016-01-12 16:29:28, Info                  CBS    Could not get active session for current session file logging [HRESULT = 0x80004003 - E_POINTER]

2016-01-12 16:29:28, Info                  CBS    Not able to add pending.xml to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]

2016-01-12 16:29:28, Info                  CBS    Not able to add pending.xml.bad to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]

2016-01-12 16:29:28, Error                 CSI    00003a8e (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #6719791# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::CDirectory::OpenExistingDirectory(...)[gle=0xd0000034]

2016-01-12 16:29:28, Error                 CSI    00003a8f (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #6719790# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::CDirectory_IRtlDirectoryTearoff::OpenExistingDirectory(flags = 0, da = (SYNCHRONIZE), oa = @0x10f864b9b0->SIL_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {s:40; on:"amd64_wstorflt.inf.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_en-us_a5cd47a48d2fba30"; a:(OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE)}, sa = (FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE), oo = (FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE|FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT|FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT), dir = NULL, disp = Invalid)
[gle=0xd0000034]`

I apologize for poor formatting.

Any ideas on what I can try?

Comment: How about you [edit] and include `cbs.log` (at least the error parts) in you question?

Comment: @DavidPostill I have added CBS.log info, thank you.